# Make Beamer slide in one order and display them in another one

Tags: beamer

I'd like to produce a first set of slides (questions) followed by slides of their answers (because they are calculated together), then a second set of questions and their answers

But show all questions first and only after all the answers.

At compilation :

1. Set A of questions
2. Set A of answers
3. Set B of questions that are inserted between 1/ and 2/
4. Set B of answers that comes normally after 2/

At show :

1. Set A of questions
2. Set B of questions
3. Set A of answers
4. Set B of answers

Is it possible ?

Comment: You are thinking about a single `frame` environment where you will insert questions and answers (without leaving the `frame` env), right?

Comment: I thaught about a kind of automatic link that will point on the begining of the next set.

Comment: would it be possible to set up some kind of a MWE to show what you are trying to achieve and what your actual code looks like?

Comment: It's an automatic questionnary powered in lua, then I will make a table with the answers. Each set of questions will add his answers in it and I'll ask to process it at the end. It's a better approach. Sorry for loss of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\only{}` with non-sequential numbering, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Q\&A}
\only<1>{%
Question from set A

Another question from set A
}
\only<3>{%
Answer from set A

Another answer from set A
}
\only<2>{%
Question from set B

Another question from set B
}
\only<4>{%
Answer from set B

Another answer from set B
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could be that, but I use one frame per second to do a countdown in the title of the frame. on can do the countdown in the frame, it will use only{} to. So it will be hard to apply your method. I thaught about a kind of automatic link that will point on the begining of the next set. Btw set A knows nothing about set B, you don't know in advance the overlay number of the biginning of answers of set A.

Comment: I see. In that case, have a look at Section 11.1 in the beamer manual. It gives examples of how to add hyperlinks and buttons, which you can use to jump between frames. You would have to make your answers on a separate frame, though.

Comment: No, because the questions have to run by themselves, without an operator intervention. I understand that it is not the good approach, I have to reserve the answers and compile them at the end.